# How do I remove the pop up upon clicking custom button referencing a visualforce page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, dynamic-visualforce

When i am clicking the custom button popup is coming and then redirecting to page.

```
<apex:page  action="{!onLoad}" standardController="account" extensions="MyPage_Controller"  >
  <apex:form>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

---

```
public class MyPage_Controller {
  public MyPage_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
  }
  public PageReference onLoad(){
    PageReference pgref = new PageReference('http://www.google.com');
    pgref.setRedirect(true);
    return pgref;
  }
}
```

How to avoid that automatic popup to come before redirection

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE. What popup? It's not clear what you're trying to avoid. Please read about [ask], then [edit] your question to include a screenshot and a better description of what's going on, as well as the button definition.

Comment: I have created custom button and added visualforce page .